# Elasticsearch Add additional condition if type is different

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, dsl

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "fragmentId": "1"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "type": "fragment"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "fragmentId": "1"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "type": "cf"
                }
              },
              {
                "range" :{
                  "start": {
                    "gte": 1,
                    "lte": 5
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am looking for two documents, one which has fragment id = 1, and type = fragment, whereas another where fragment id = 1, type = "cf" and start between 1 and 5.
The above query is doing the job, but I need to write type and fragment id twice. Is there a way I can add range condition only when the type is cf, basically clubbing both bools in one ?

Comment: You can club the `fragmentId` bit cause it is exactly the same. Rest you cannot. They are two seperate queries. If you mix them up you cannot let them match **exclusively**

Answer (score 1):

This is the query you're looking for:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "fragmentId": "1"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "fragment"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "type": "cf"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "start": {
                    "gte": 1,
                    "lte": 5
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes this helps in re-structuring the query correctly. But is it possible to write a query in such a way that if type =" fragment" and fragment id = 1, is not present, then it should not pick the other document with type="cf".  Basically i want the combo of both document, or else no result.

Comment: So you need a AND not an OR between both conditions.

Comment: yes, but if i add AND it will apply to all the documents. what i want is everytime result comes in pair, of type = "fragment" and type="cf" join by fragmentID="1"

Comment: How can a document have type "fragment" and "cf" at the same time? or are you talking about to different data types that you store in the same index? Maybe show some sample documents that you expect to come back in the results.

Comment: No, it's not the same document. type="fragment" is a parent with fragmentid="1" , and it has multiple child with type = "cf" and fragmentid="1". All these child have different start number, which differentiates them. Now, in my query, I want parent plus child , where child start is 1-5. I don't want only parent document, if condition for child ( id=1, type="cf" , start=1-5) not met in any child document

Comment: It would have been great that you mention this parent/child relationship in your question, because the approach is totally different